# The verb that follows "help"

Tags: grammar, verbs

I wrote:

> MD simulations can help **[to]** gain molecular-level insights into the behavior of solutes in a specific biphasic system.

I'm not sure if it is "help gain" or "help to gain", or maybe "help gaining"; the second sounds more natural to me. I know we can say "help me find/gain/etc." but saying "help find/gain/etc." sounds odd to me. Could you please say what is the rule for these cases (with and without an object)

Answer (score 1):

Note the the use of gerund suggests a different connotation:

***[Help](https://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-mean-help)*** can be followed by either a gerund or a (to-)infinitive but with different meanings:

> I can't help thinking that you are hiding something. (only in the negative: I have to think that you are hiding something.)
>
> Could you help me (to) undo my shoelaces? My fingers are frozen. (Could you undo my shoelaces?)
>
> ***Help can be followed by a bare infinitive or a to-infinitive.***

Comment: Thank you but you still didn't answer my question. My example have no object between the "help" and the following verb. Can you say, for example, "This help find a solution"

Comment: @Ahmad - as stated in the answer, you can use both to-infinitive or bare infinitive. See also : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+find%2C+help+to+find&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20find%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20to%20find%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Ahmad It doesn't matter. You could have written "MD simulations can help *you* gain molecular-level insights into the behavior of solutes in a specific biphasic system." I would go with the bare infinitive.